# My code doesn't work when using scanf("%c")

Tags: c

So i have this code which is meant to take two user inputs "int height" and "char symbol". The code will then call a function that will create a triangle out of ascii which is "height" lines tall, and is filled with ascii "symbols"s.

However. When i try to get the user input for the symbol. The program skips it and crashes. I've noticed that it only seems to happen when i call the height before it. And i have no clue why. any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
void print_triangle(int height, char symbol)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");

        for (int j = 1; j < (height - i); j++) //this will print the correct amount of spaces per line to shape the triangle
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

        printf("/"); // printf one side of triangle 

        for (int k = 0; k < (i * 2); k++)  // print the correct number of symbols per line to fill the triangle
        {
            printf("%c", symbol);
        }

        printf("\\");  // print the other side of the triangle

    }

    printf("\n");  // next line
}


int main()
{
    int height;
    char symbol;

    printf("Height? ");
    scanf("%d", &height);   // read triangle height

    printf("Symbol? ");
    scanf("%c", &symbol);  // THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM OCCURS. I CANT READ THE SYMBOL.

    print_triangle(height, symbol);   //call function

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because it is consuming the newline character remained from the previous `scanf`...

Comment: @EugeneSh. It would print newlines instead of the char in the input on the next line; but why crash?

Comment: `scanf("%c", &symbol);`  ==>> `scanf(" %c", &symbol);` You see the space there?

Comment: It should not crash.

Comment: @nick Try to read a string into a buffer and use the first char. %s skips newline and other whitespace, %c does not. It's a beginner's puzzle: hitting enter commits the input, true; but it also inserts the character \n in the input which is read by %c.

Comment: Thanks everyone! i managed to fix it using a space [scanf(" %c")].

However, can somebody explain what it means to consume a newline in a new scanf? im struggling to understand that

Comment: @nickyeyes You should check `scanf` [For errors too](http://ideone.com/Sdfdqh)

Comment: @George [This is a working Code](http://ideone.com/DFGixL)

Comment: @nickyeyes the previous entry has left a `newline` in the input buffer, categorised as "whitespace". The `space` added before `%c` cleans off any such whitespace still in the input buffer. This is explained in the dup. However other formats such as `%s` and `%d` clean off this whitespace *automatically*. This is not the case with `%c`.